# Kurento : Tutorial 4 - One to one video call not working on Azure

Tags: webrtc, kurento

I have deployed kurento java tutorial on a virtual machine (Ubuntu-14.04) on Azure. I was able to execute/test Tutorial 1 to Tutorial 3 successfully, However Tutorial-4 & Tutorial-5  is not working. During one2one call I'm not able to receive peer media stream. The required UDP/TCP was open as well.

I have provided the required STUN configuration in `WebRtcEndpoint.conf.ini` & `kurento.conf.json`

```
stunServerAddress=74.125.142.127
stunServerPort=19302

"stunServerAddress" : "74.125.142.127",
"stunServerPort" : 19302
```

I tried debugging, but could not find any error in logs.

```
Logs : 
2015-12-19 11:35:28,919387 5451 [0x00007ff22dffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:52 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:2 1 UDP 1677721855 13.67.48.97 1040 typ srflx raddr 10.146.240.34 rport 59342","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"},"source":"4847259d-b524-4e6f-9d04-edf79b6cd7f5_kurento.MediaPipeline/45185a24-52f0-4cee-a22b-d207a873a50f_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1450524928","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"4847259d-b524-4e6f-9d04-edf79b6cd7f5_kurento.MediaPipeline/45185a24-52f0-4cee-a22b-d207a873a50f_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 -> 60129de0-44f3-4de9-abe7-8fc32d08a80e
2015-12-19 11:35:28,919680 5451 [0x00007ff22dffb700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:52 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:2 1 UDP 1677721855 13.67.48.97 1040 typ srflx raddr 10.146.240.34 rport 59342","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"},"source":"4847259d-b524-4e6f-9d04-edf79b6cd7f5_kurento.MediaPipeline/45185a24-52f0-4cee-a22b-d207a873a50f_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1450524928","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"4847259d-b524-4e6f-9d04-edf79b6cd7f5_kurento.MediaPipeline/45185a24-52f0-4cee-a22b-d207a873a50f_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 -> 60129de0-44f3-4de9-abe7-8fc32d08a80e
2015-12-19 11:35:28,931921 5451 [0x00007ff2177fe700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:52 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:2 1 UDP 1677721855 13.67.48.97 1042 typ srflx raddr 10.146.240.34 rport 37000","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"},"source":"4847259d-b524-4e6f-9d04-edf79b6cd7f5_kurento.MediaPipeline/2bced6d1-e7f8-49da-a37a-e98cf9ce9a5d_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1450524928","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"4847259d-b524-4e6f-9d04-edf79b6cd7f5_kurento.MediaPipeline/2bced6d1-e7f8-49da-a37a-e98cf9ce9a5d_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 -> 60129de0-44f3-4de9-abe7-8fc32d08a80e
2015-12-19 11:35:28,932150 5451 [0x00007ff2177fe700]   debug KurentoWebSocketEventHandler WebSocketEventHandler.cpp:52 sendEvent()  Sending event: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:2 1 UDP 1677721855 13.67.48.97 1042 typ srflx raddr 10.146.240.34 rport 37000","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"},"source":"4847259d-b524-4e6f-9d04-edf79b6cd7f5_kurento.MediaPipeline/2bced6d1-e7f8-49da-a37a-e98cf9ce9a5d_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1450524928","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"4847259d-b524-4e6f-9d04-edf79b6cd7f5_kurento.MediaPipeline/2bced6d1-e7f8-49da-a37a-e98cf9ce9a5d_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
 -> 60129de0-44f3-4de9-abe7-8fc32d08a80e
2015-12-19 11:35:43,950679 5451 [0x00007ff24a7fc700]    info KurentoWebSocketTransport WebSocketTransport.cpp:257 keepAliveSessions()  Keep alive 60129de0-44f3-4de9-abe7-8fc32d08a80e
2015-12-19 11:36:43,951659 5451 [0x00007ff24a7fc700]    info KurentoWebSocketTransport WebSocketTransport.cpp:257 keepAliveSessions()  Keep alive 60129de0-44f3-4de9-abe7-8fc32d08a80e
2015-12-19 11:37:43,948660 5451 [0x00007ff25451f700]   debug KurentoMediaSet           MediaSet.cpp:131 doGarbageCollection()  Running garbage collector
2015-12-19 11:37:43,952370 5451 [0x00007ff24a7fc700]    info KurentoWebSocketTransport WebSocketTransport.cpp:257 keepAliveSessions()  Keep alive 60129de0-44f3-4de9-abe7-8fc32d08a80e
2015-12-19 11:38:43,952796 5451 [0x00007ff24a7fc700]    info KurentoWebSocketTransport WebSocketTransport.cpp:257 keepAliveSessions()  Keep alive 60129de0-44f3-4de9-abe7-8fc32d08a80e
```

Comment: There is no need to add anything in `kurento.conf.json`, as all the configurations about webrtc have been moved to the other file you modified. Could you please check the connection with the command `stun -v 74.125.142.127:19302`? In the output of that command, you should see your public IP. If you don't get that public IP, then there is something with your Azure installation.

Comment: Initially I didn't do any change in kurento.conf.json, But as one2one call wasn't working i  added the stun config in kurento.conf.json as trial and error method. I tried all the combination. Even the stun config (stun -v 74.125.142.127:19302) is working
Log for STUN :

About to send msg of len 28 to 13.67.48.97:1040
Received stun message: 28 bytes
ChangeRequest = 0
Received message of type 1  id=11
Received stun message: 32 bytes
MappedAddress = 13.67.48.97:1041
Received message of type 257  id=2
Received stun message: 32 bytes
Received stun message: 32 bytes
MappedAddress = 13.67.48.97:1041

Comment: Ok, that is working, as the first tutorials are working. There is no difference with the other two, or at least there shouldn't be. Do you get any errors in client, server app or KMS logs?

Answer (score 2):

This has been cross-posted and answered in the [project's mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/kurento/azure%7Csort:date/kurento/0_ohTelSpnw/oH6BLIssDQAJ).

Long story short, seems like Azure only allows opening 150 ports (as per the info provided by the poster), so Kurento needs to be configured to limit the range of ports used. This can be achieved modifying the contents of the file `/etc/kurento/modules/kurento/BaseRtpEndpoint.conf.ini`